# Adding methods to EntityFramework DBset

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I am working with EntityFramework 5, .NET 4.5 C#. I want to add custom SQL to the Member DBset. I want to be able to select by `Name` and `Surname` using the following statement

```
RosteringDBContainer db = new RosteringDBContainer();
var results = db.Members.Select("dave", "davidson"); //first name and surname
```

This should execute the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Member
WHERE Name='{0}'
AND Surname='{1}';
```

I know that i can do this using extension methods and `db.Members.Execute("SQL Here");`, i just want to know if there is some more explicit way of doing this.

[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: I see nothing that would be stopping you from using LINQ here...

Comment: LINQ would work, but i want to be able to use this method to perform more complex SQL (such as calling a stored procedure). Also, as the tables are quite large, i am concerned about the performance of a LINQ query.

Comment: Stored procedure is a valid argument. About 'performance' tough, I'd first try the LINQ version (unless the query is really complicated, the SQL generated is quite decent), check the execution plan and see if there's any real difference between those approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an extension method for RosteringDBContainer.Members and use linq to get the desired result, code would look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Member> SelectMembers(this DbSet<Member> members, string name, string surname)
{
 return from m in members 
        where m.Name == name and m.Surname == usrname
        select m;
}
```

Comment: will that LINQ statement execute the required SQL?

Comment: Yes if Name and Surname is part of Member class, if not you need to use joins to get to the entity which holds those properties

Comment: Excellent. Can you link me to an article that explains how LINQ translates to SQL so that i can learn more for future reference? I want to make sure it isn't doing a `SELECT *` then iterating over the results

Comment: It uses exression trees to parse to translate the linq query to sql, here is a quick overview http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/37/dynamic-queries-in-entity-framework-using-expression-trees

Comment: Here is a link, if you want to view the generated queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136558/view-ef4-generated-queries